# Como alterar cores em gráficos utilizando matplotlib

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib, cores

Criei um gráfico de pontos utilizando matplotlib, porém estou querendo colocar a seguinte condição:
Para os pontos acima de zero ( > 0) em Y pintar de verde e para os pontos abaixo de zero ( < 0) pintar de vermelho.

```
plt.plot(df2["Status"], 'o')
plt.ylabel('Eixo Y')
plt.xlabel('Eixo X')
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, se você quer plotar um gráfico de pontos/espalhamento (*scatter plot*), utilize a função `plt.scatter`.

Nesse tipo de gráfico, o que você precisa é de uma sequência informando qual a cor correspondente de cada ponto plotado. Como você está trabalhando com um `DataFrame`, podemos criar uma coluna nova nele com os valores `"green"` e `"red"` e passar esta coluna com ao argumento `c` (de *color*) do `plt.scatter`.

Para gerar esta coluna com as cores, podemos utilizar o método `apply` de uma coluna de `DataFrame`: ao escrevermos `col.apply(func)`, o pandas passa cada elemento da coluna `col` pela função `func`, retornando uma coluna de mesmo tamanho. Aí é só escrever a lógica da função para retornar `"green"` ou `"red"` de acordo com o valor de entrada.

Exemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Gera um DataFrame com coluna Status (200 valores aleatórios entre -1 e 1)
ys = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 200)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Status": ys})


# Função auxiliar contendo a lógica de como colorir cada ponto
def cor_do_ponto(valor: float) -> str:
    """Retorna a cor de um ponto do gráfico, de acordo com o seu valor."""
    if valor > 0:
        return "green"
    else:
        return "red"

# Cria uma nova coluna aplicando a função a cada ponto da coluna Status
df['Color'] = df['Status'].apply(cor_do_ponto)

# Plota o resultado
plt.scatter(df.index, df['Status'], c=df['Color'])
plt.ylabel('Eixo Y')
plt.xlabel('Eixo X')
plt.show()
```

Como a função `plt.scatter` precisa de valores explícitos da coordenada X de cada ponto, passei o próprio índice do `DataFrame`, que por padrão é uma sequência numérica crescente indo de zero até `len(df) - 1`.

Ah, um detalhe: note que, pela lógica da nossa função, se algum valor for *exatamente zero* sua cor será vermelha também.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]